# 'this' value in an array of objects undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of routes. Each route is it's own object which gets iterated to define. I would expect to be able to use the header key within main() using the 'this' keyword, but it's undefined. What am I missing here?

```
const loggedInRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    exact: true,
    isPrivate: true,
    header: 'Home',
    main() {
      console.log(this); // undefined
      return (
        <HeadWrap header={this.header}> // property 'header' undefined
          <Home />
        </HeadWrap>
      );
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: I got it! Using the getter returned the returned object (go figure lol), but what I needed was a function! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why this works, but what I was trying originally does not.
```
let user = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

user.sayHi();  // John
```